# Cannot use LazyListScope.items with PagingData in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-jetpack, android-paging-3, lazycolumn

I've been following an Udemy course and in their source code there's this code within a Composable function:

```
LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(SMALL_PADDING),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(SMALL_PADDING)
        ) {
            items(
                items = heroes,
                key = { hero -> hero.id }
            ) { hero ->
                hero?.let {
                    HeroItem(hero = it, navController = navController)
                }

            }
        }
```

However, when I try it, it throws 2 errors:

1. **At Line 5 of the above block**: items(..)  : `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:<br/>public inline fun &lt;T&gt; LazyListScope.items(items: Array&lt;TypeVariable(T)&gt;, noinline key: ((item: TypeVariable(T)) -&gt; Any)? = ..., noinline contentType: (item: TypeVariable(T)) -&gt; Any? = ..., crossinline itemContent: LazyItemScope.(item: TypeVariable(T)) -&gt; Unit): Unit defined in androidx.compose.foundation.lazy<br/>public inline fun &lt;T&gt; LazyListScope.items(items: List&lt;TypeVariable(T)&gt;, noinline key: ((item: TypeVariable(T)) -&gt; Any)? = ..., noinline contentType: (item: TypeVariable(T)) -&gt; Any? = ..., crossinline itemContent: LazyItemScope.(item: TypeVariable(T)) -&gt; Unit): Unit defined in androidx.compose.foundation.lazy`
2. **At Line 10 of the above block**: HeroItem(..):  `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

The Code block screenshot:
[Code block screenshot from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5sLE.png)

My "items" : [Screenshot of "items" hover from my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6fRE.png)

Their "items" : [Screenshot of their "items" hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U15c.png)

I don't appear to be using the same "items" as them but from my understanding the "items" they're using is deprecated and I cannot find it. I am not sure how to modify their code so that it works.

I believe I have all the dependencies as necessary. The project is using several dependencies, including Room, Paging3, DaggerHilt, Coil, among others.

I have looked for a solution of this but it doesn't seem to work. I would really appreciate a solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: threre are many ```items``` function in ```LazyColumn``` so import relevant function to avoid errors

Comment: Can you tell me what import to use?

Comment: Here is the complete example you can follow. https://github.com/mohammadjoumani/paging_movie_app_jetpack_compose/tree/main

Comment: This is usually solved when you Alt+Enter on the function that has this type of problem.

Comment: @ChiragThummar thanks for your example, it gave me a tentative solution. I will update the question when I'm sure of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the cause of the problem and the solution of the same. The `LazyPagingItems` form of `items` has been deprecated. The alternative solution is:

```
// LazyColumn above
  items(count = heroes.itemCount, key = heroes.itemKey { hero -> hero.id }) { index ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                index.let {
                    val item = heroes[it]!!
                    HeroItem(hero = item, navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is the following import statement to use `items` function:
**import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items**

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Actually there are multiple `items` function in jetpack compose so sometimes the android studio unable to import the actual one so we have to manually do that.

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

This problem will also get resolved after import the proper `items` function mentioned above.